# TypeScript export-import conventions

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, conventions

In contrast to Java (and other languages), TypeScript offers you multiple ways to export and import things (classes, functions etc.).
For example, you can `export` multiple classes, constants, functions etc. per file.
Also you can define 1 default export per file.
On the other side you can `import` only the default `export`, import everything using an alias or import the given things.
Coming from Java, I wonder, if there is any convention, especially regarding `constant`s and `function`s.
Let's say I have a util-file, having a lot of `function`s. In Java I would create a `File` `Util.java` with `class Util`, which contains all the `static function`s.
In `TypeScript` I have following possibilities:

1. Export every single function and import it using `import * as Util`.
2. Create a `class Util` with `static function`s and export only this class.

In both cases I can call functions using `Util.functionName()`, just like in java.

Another case is a `class` with a few `constant`s.
For example I have a `class Car` with a field `type`. There are also constants for the available `type`s, like `TYPE_SUV`, `TYPE_SPORT` and so on.

Again, I can define them as "top-level" constants and export them and the class `Car`. But I can also define them as `public static readonly` inside the `Car`-class and export that class only.
Using the first approach, I would have a verry big `import` statement, if I need all constants in other files. Also sub-classes won't "inherit" those constants.
However using `readonly` instead of `const` feels kind of strange to me...

So I was looking for some kind of convention, but I did not find much.
I only found a few tips like [`this`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html).

So, are there any guidelines regarding exports and imports in TypeScript, which take care about the explained problems? I am also looking for the best way, regarding integration of tools (refactoring, auto-importing, organizing imports etc.).

Thanks.

Comment: Java also has `import static package.Util.functionName`, by the way, for static methods and variables. In both cases importing a subset of what's available initializes both namespaces fully (class and js-file respectively). Other than that, answer to this lies in some place with whether you indent you code with tabs or spaces, and how much of each of those a good programmer needs in their life.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks for your opinion. You are right about `import static`, however it seems to be rarely used. As I am pretty new to TypeScript I don't have a preference on that yet, so I wanted to choose the thing, that tools (IDEs, Editors etc.) like the most. For example `default exports` seem to cause problems with refactoring.

Comment: I started to use static imports a lot more when Hamcrest and Java 8 came  along, personally, because `stream.collect(Collectors.toList())` is a little shorter without `Collectors` in the middle. As for tool and refactoring, - it at least looks to me that there is more than one way to express same import in JS, so tools get confused, but tools will eventually catch up anyway. You should choose what's better for _you_ to read, not for machines.

Comment: In the perfect case, I wouldn't even need to read the imports as they are fully managed by the tools. In eclipse with java, I never need to take care about the import. I use organize imports and everythig is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am afraid this is going to be somewhat opinion based although there are objective elements in choosing one over another)

> 1. Export every single function and import it using import * as Util.
> 2. Create a class Util with static functions and export only this class.

I prefer number 1) because 2) does not bring any benefit and may lead to someone instantiating the `Util` class for no reason (and contrarily to Java, this cannot be prevented).

> I can define them as "top-level" constants and export them and the class Car. But I can also define them as `public static readonly` inside the Car-class and export that class only.

With regards to constants, the `readonly` modifier only applies at compile time. So as class properties, they can still be modified at runtime. I, hence, prefer to make them top level constants in the module (file)

The excellent handbook from Basarat is also my "reference" and I share his opinion on default exports which do not bring much aside from confusion since with named exports, it is also possible to rename on import e.g.

```
import { OriginalName as MyPreferredName}  from './OriginalName'
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! The benefit of creating a class `Util` would be, that the imports look the same everywhere. Also I am a bit afraid of tooling (like `rename` the function, would it be renamed in Util if i `import * as Util`?). Also with the constants I have the problem, that I need to import 10+ constants or write `import * as XYZ`. That makes it imposible to use `classname.constant`, as I would do in java.

Comment: I understand.. but this not Java :) (I program in both too). Things are less "constant" and "final" in the JS world, so I prefer the safe side to good looking imports. Now 1) you can have named imports: `import {myFunction} from './Util'` rather than namespacing everything wih `import * as ns` and 2) my IDE (IDEA) is good at refactoring; some devs here use VSCOde, which looks good at it too

Comment: Okay. Thanks again for your opinion. One last thing: Do you usually preffer to import every single thing of a file (if there are many) or import everything using * ?

Comment: I prefer to import every single element in order to avoid the namespace i.e. I prefer to write `myImportedFunc` to `util.myImportedFunc`. When there are names conflicts it is possible to rename named exports on import i.e. `import {conflictingName as otherName} from './Myfile'`

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. +1